# JAVA Use different paint() methods with multiple threads Java

Tags: java, multithreading, paint

I'm new to Java.
Is it possible to call different paint() methods at all?
I need to create running different strings in 4 separate threads. Left-right, Right-Left, Down-UP, Up-Down.

I've got an idea to use paint in each thread, clearing only used space and painting on it again and again. I hope there is more intelligent way...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Program extends Applet implements Runnable
{
    Thread t, t1;
    int x = 10, y = 10;

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            //this.getGraphics().clearRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
            //paint(this.getGraphics());
            try
            {
                x++;
                t.sleep(10);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
              }     
        }
    }
    public void init () {
    setSize(400, 200);
    t = new Thread(this);   
    t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    t1.sleep(10);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  } 
            }
        }
   });  
    t.start();
   t1.start();

    }
      public void paint(Graphics g) 
      { 
          g.drawString("Test", x, y);       
      } 
}
```

So, I'm looking how to create and use another paint() in t2.

Comment: You'll want to clarify your question greatly. Painting is GUI library dependent, and so the answer will depend fully on what GUI library (Swing? SWT? AWT? Android?) you are talking about. Also give more details and perhaps some code. Often you may think you need a bunch of threads when only 2 are needed. Let's hear more about your problem and your program structure and code.

Comment: Also, if this is a Swing question, then you'd never call the painting method directly.

Comment: it's just task from, so i need 4 threads, using awt library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main extends Applet implements Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Thread thread1, thread2, thread3, thread4;
    int x = 10, y = 10;
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel(" text1 runs from left to right "), label2 = new JLabel("text2 runs in good way here  ");//, label3 = new JLabel("text3"), label4 = new JLabel("text4");
    RotatedLabel label3 = new RotatedLabel("text3 runs in a bad way("), label4  = new RotatedLabel("t4 runs UP-Down all the time  ");
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                thread1.sleep(1);
                thread2.sleep(1);
                thread3.sleep(1);
                thread4.sleep(1);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
              }     
        }
    }
    public void init () {
        setSize(400, 200);
        setLayout(null);
        label1.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(1, 1), label1.getPreferredSize()));
        label2.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(1, 1), label2.getPreferredSize()));
        label3.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(1, 1), label3.getPreferredSize()));
        label4.setDirection(RotatedLabel.Direction.VERTICAL_UP);
        label4.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(1, 1), label4.getPreferredSize()));
        label3.setDirection(RotatedLabel.Direction.VERTICAL_DOWN);
        this.add(label1);
        this.add(label2);
        this.add(label3);
        this.add(label4);
        thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        label1.setLocation(100, 180);
                        String text = label1.getText();
                        String text2 = text.substring(1)+  text.substring(0,1);
                        label1.setText(text2);
                        thread1.sleep(500);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      } 
                }
            }
       });
        thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        label2.setLocation(100, 20);
                        String text = label2.getText();
                        String text2 = text.substring(text.length()-1)+  text.substring(0,text.length()-1);
                        label2.setText(text2);
                        thread2.sleep(500);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      } 
                }
            }
       });
        thread3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        label3.setLocation(80, 28);
                        String text = label1.getText();
                        String text2 = text.substring(1)+  text.substring(0,1);
                        label3.setText(text2);
                        label3.setSize(10, 180);
                        thread3.sleep(500);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      } 
                }
            }
       });
        thread4 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        label4.setLocation(268, 25);
                        String text = label4.getText();
                        String text2 = text.substring(1)+  text.substring(0,1);
                        label4.setText(text2);


                        thread4.sleep(500);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      } 
                }
            }
       });
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();
        }
}
```